# Ruby mechanize Form

Tags: ruby, forms, mechanize

Is there anyway to copy the out put of forms available to a file, like

```
require 'mechanize' 
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.google.com")
search = page.form_with(:action => "/search")
```

I want to store the result/output which is shown in irb of the "search" to a file?

Comment: Use Unix redirection operator to save then in a file..

Comment: I tried but, its telling "unknown regexp options "

Comment: You mean each search link per page or ?

Comment: No, like u see, I stores the value of page.form_with(:action => "/search")  to search, I need the output of search to a file. Like, if we type in irb, search the returned output.